# How to see the output this code on my console in a swift

Tags: swift

[image]

Hello, I want to examine the output of this code, but somehow I cannot see the output on the screen in Xcode.

```
    func numerator() {
        let nums = [2,7,11,15]
        let target = 26
        
        for i in nums{
            for (index, j) in nums.enumerated() {
                if i+j == target {
                    print(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to run it some how. Using `Preview`, a command line app, etc

Comment: I don't want any edits to my code. how can i see console output only i ask it in Xcode.As you can see in the image, there is no output in the console when you run Xcode. I can get the output of the region I want when I click on the button in xcode

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is a playground project you need to call the function. simply do `numerator()` after the function (on line 25)

to address @jnpdx this code should work as the code isn't trying to add index's to values, it looks like you're adding the values of the array together, so eventually it should do `11 + 15` which should print the line.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to your problem:

1. How do you run the above code
2. How do you view the output.

For item 1, you could run it as a command line application, and playground, or as a Mac or iOS app that doesn't display any UI. I tend to use Mac command line apps for testing simple code. You will need to call your `numerator()` function somewhere or its code won't be executed.

For item 2, you can open the Xcode debugger window and view the console output. Are you sure your code will ever execute your print statement?

Here is a complete command line tool that will test your code.

```
import Foundation

func numerator() {
    let nums = [2,7,11,15]
    let target = 26

    for i in nums{
        for (index, j) in nums.enumerated() {
            if i+j == target {
                print(index)
            }
        }
    }
}

print("About to call 'numerator()'")
numerator()
print("back from call to 'numerator()'")
```

That outputs the following:

```
About to call 'numerator()'
3
2
back from call to 'numerator()'
```